# Can I call a .CMD file from a .BAT file and move on with processing?

Tags: batch-file

We are trying to create a reboot process for one of our batch servers.  We have a batch file that is initially called by a scheduling program that checks some logs to make sure processing on the server is complete.  We then want that batch file to call a .cmd file that is in charge of rebooting the server.  The problem we are facing is calling the shutdown command, but then moving on and exiting the original batch so that it can exit successfully to our scheduling program.

//Check logs and stuff
c:\serveradmintools\shutdown.cmd  <--- call this and move on to exit while it processes
exit 0 <--- exit to scheduling program successfully

Our shutdown program is on a 60 second delay so to give time to exit to the scheduling program.  Is this possible???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`start`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command to launch the [`shutdown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command in another thread.